# Save and Load text on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I am struggling for some hours at a problem. Basically, I have a simple Swift app. It goes like this. In my 1st view controller I have 3 text fields I want to fill them with information and a "Next" button.

Pressing the "Next" button will send me to a new UIViewController where I will have a "Back" button. Upon pressing the back button, I will be send back to 1st page with the 3 text fields.

What I want is: if I complete the text fields with informations, press Next and then Back, I want the text fields to be filled with that information.

I managed to move between the views with buttons, but I can't save the information. Can you provide me a little help?

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtb1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtb2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtb3: UITextField!


@IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {
    text1 = self.txtb1.text!
    text2 = self.txtb2.text!
    text3 = self.txtb3.text!  }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if (!text1)
        {
            txtb1.text = text1
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you please show me the  action on both next buttons?

Comment: when you click the next button, you are closing the current screen ?. when you click the back button, you are closing that screen or just presenting the screen(with text field and next button) ?.

Comment: @Signare I think in the next button of the second page he is making a new instance of the 1st View Controller and opening it  instead of dismissing the curent VC

Comment: @BashirSidani i think so. Let him post some codes.

Comment: have you tried `txtb1.text = text1` in ViewDidAppear ?

Comment: use 3 static variable and save when textfield changes. view did load assign to three text fields if the value is not empty.

Comment: Added some code, improved a little.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to pass variables to different views you will have to use the **prepareForSegue** function before you segue into that view controller.

This allows the variables to be accessed by the view controller.

```
Override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    if segue.identifier == "segue_name"
    {
        let theDestination = segue.destinationViewController as! newViewController
        theDestination.variable = "testing"
        theDestination.variable2 = "testing2"
    }
}
```

Then inside your second view controller you will have to declare variable and variable2 as shown:

```
var variable:String!
var variable2:String!
```

These will then be able to be used in the second view controller inside the **viewDidLoad** method.

Comment: I don't want the information from 1st view to the 2nd view. I just want that the information from the 1st view to be saved locally in this manner. I start app (it starts with 1st view), complete all 3 text fields, press next button, press back button, and all 3 text fields to have the values I previosly entered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I managed to fix a little of the problem, that button wasn't linked accordingly so the function was not executing. Here it is the code:

```
var text1 = ""
@IBOutlet weak var txtb1: UITextField!

@IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {

    text1 = self.txtb1.text! // text1 = "I am taking value"
}

// when i press the back button
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (!numarInmatriculare.isEmpty)
        {
            txtb1.text = text1    //here text1 = Null. the value is not saved
        }
    }
```

I want the value to be saved and displayed back on text field.

I also tried to use static varibiles but I am prompet with error.

```
static var numar:String = ""
numar = text1
//static member 'numar'cannot be used on instance of type 'viewcontroller'
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to do anything for this case, once text field filed then you clicking next button you wrote some code below i shown

```
  text1 = self.txtb1.text!
  text2 = self.txtb2.text!
  text3 = self.txtb3.text!
```

Please first you remove the code,Once data filled in text filed, its automatically retain, after you clicking next button then come back it  automatically it will retain, when your current view is poping then only your data will deallocate.